# Are there tor exit nodes (country specific) that are not listed in the tor node list?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, exit-relays

Sometimes I have to use Tor as a proxy server to let myself appear in a specific country. This can be done by editing the torrc.

Problem is: Some websites are blocking traffic from Tor. I presume they are using the list provided by Tor Project to autoblock the traffic.

Question:
Are there Tor Exit nodes (country specific) that are not listed in the Tor node list?

Comment: I don't think there are many private Tor exit nodes. https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2012-August/003897.html I think just a simple proxy may be better for your uses.

Answer (score 1):

No, because using them is not practical at all. You'd have to change your Tor heavily to make use of them, and even then it'd not offer you most of Tor's anonymity protections if any kind of link between you and the exit node can be established.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to have ones: tor network consensus lists all the nodes online and their roles, so if the node is not listen in the consensus with an exit node capability - there will be no way to use it as an exit. A different situation if you're talking about some outside lists provided by third parties - yes, in this case if a new node was listed and it was not included into the list - in this case you can have an unlisted exit case

Answer (score 0):

It can happen, they are Tor entry, middle or exit points with unknown country allocation.

You can exclude tor nodes with unknown coutrys allocation by your torrc file on follow way:

ExcludeNodes {??}, {DE} StrictNodes 1

Possible this can help you by your question.